# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'is_active' (PyMongo And Flask)

Tags: python, flask, pymongo, flask-login

```
@app.route("/register", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        users = mongo.db.users
        hash_password=bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data).decode('utf-8')
        eml=form.email.data
        gen=form.gender.data
        ctry=form.country.data
        profile={'name' : form.username.data, 'password' :hash_password,'email':eml,'gender':gen,'country':ctry}
        users.insert(profile)
        #users.insert({'name' : form.username.data, 'password' :form.password.data})
        flash(f'Your has been Account created for Username {form.username.data}!, You can login', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
        #return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('register.html', title='Register', form=form)

@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        users = mongo.db.users
        loginuser = users.find_one({'email' : form.email.data})
        if loginuser and bcrypt.check_password_hash(loginuser['password'],form.password.data):
        #if form.email.data == 'admin@blog.com' and form.password.data == 'password':
            login_user(loginuser,remember=form.data.remember)
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
            #flash('You have been logged in!', 'success')
            #return redirect(url_for('home'))
        else:
            flash('Login Unsuccessful. Please check username and password', 'danger')
    return render_template('login.html', title='Login', form=form)
```

I have created a simple register and login method using flask with combination of pymongo.
Now for user session management i am using flask_login 
but it gives me this error 
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'is_active'

the solution that i found different post was to add UserMaxIn in UserClass 
but i dont have any class for User Model and i dont want to make it either

what would be the solution of this error  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flask-Login requires that you use a class to represent users, not a raw dict.

As described in [documentation](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#your-user-class), this class needs to implement some properties and methods, included the `is_active()` method.

The `UserMixin` class is the base class that provides default implementations for all the required properties and methods and you can extend it and create a simple User class.

---

**Update**: added example

Based on what you already have, the simplest thing you can do is:

- create a custom `User` class that extends `UserMixin`
- store the `json` object from MongoDB inside the `User` class
- override the methods for which you require a behavior different from the default one
- In the `/login` route create an instance of the `User` class and pass it to `flask_login.login_user()`

#### User class

```
class User(UserMixin):
    def __init__(self, user_json):
        self.user_json = user_json

    # Overriding get_id is required if you don't have the id property
    # Check the source code for UserMixin for details
    def get_id(self):
        object_id = self.user_json.get('_id')
        return str(object_id)
```

For all the methods/properties (`is_authenticated`, `is_active`, `is_anonymous`), except `get_id` it uses the default implementations. If you don't need the default implementations you don't need to extend `UserMixin` but you have to implement all the methods by yourself.

#### Usage of the User class in login route

```
@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        users = mongo.db.users
        loginuser_json = users.find_one({'email': form.email.data})
        if loginuser_json and bcrypt.check_password_hash(loginuser_json['password'], form.password.data):
            # Create a custom user and pass it to login_user:
            loginuser = User(loginuser_json)
            login_user(loginuser, remember=form.data.remember)
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
        else:
            flash('Login Unsuccessful. Please check username and password', 'danger')
    return render_template('login.html', title='Login', form=form)
```

Remember that you also have to provide a `user_loader` as described [here](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#how-it-works). For example, given the `user_id`, perform a query on MongoDB and return the `User` object:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    users = mongo.db.users
    user_json = users.find_one({'_id': ObjectId(user_id)})
    return User(user_json)
```

#### Useful links

- [Flask-Login documentation](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [`UserMixin` source code](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/flask_login/mixins.html#UserMixin)
- [A more complete User class](https://realpython.com/using-flask-login-for-user-management-with-flask/)

Comment: Can you give me a simple code for creating User class ? and how to call that class in login route

Comment: Thanks Alot , Its working
By the way how to get current user email ?

Comment: You can get it from the json object: `loginuser_json.get('email')`.  
If you want to get it from a `User` object: `user_object.user_json.get('email')` or you can add a new method `get_email` inside the `User` class.

Comment: def get_mail(self):
        object_id = self.user_json.get('email')
        return str(object_id)

like this ?

Comment: yes it works but the email is already string so you can simply:
`def get_mail(self): return self.user_json.get('email')`

Comment: <p> {{ current_user.email }}  </p>

but it displays
<bound method User.get_mail of <cbrs.routes.User object at 0x00000276E5C78C50>>

Comment: @usman You are trying to call it from Jinja template? You have to add to Jinja globals the function you want to call. The simplest think you can do is: `<p> {{ current_user.user_json.email }} </p>`. But if you have problems that do not concern the original question I suggest you to ask a new one.